# jQuery Forum Submission By Hitting Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms

I have an unusual problem with a form (here's a slimmed down version):

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $("form").submit(function(){ 
            alert('Checkout time!'); 
        });
        $("button[name='process_order']").click(function(){ 
            alert('Button Checkout time!'); 
        });
        $("button[name='back']").click(function(){ 
            alert('Back Button'); 
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="moo1" tabindex="1" />
    <input type="text" name="moo2" tabindex="2" />
    <button name="back" tabindex="4">Back</button>
    <button name="process_order" tabindex="3">Process Order</button>
</form>
```

The buttons work fine, however, if I hit enter when one of the textboxes that has focus, the 'Back Button' action is what fires... even though the form's submit handler is set to do "checkout"...

Comment: How about avoiding the conflict introduced by the two buttons and just setting the `back` action up as a styled link?

Comment: A button in a form is, by default, a submit button. Replace it with a type button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably change the process_order tothis:

`<input type="submit" name="process_order" value="Process Order" tabindex="3" />`

And change  to:

`<form id="myForm">`

Then, bind the .submit() handler to it

```
$('#myForm').submit(function()
{
    alert('Button checkout time!');
    return false; //we return false so that it doesn't refresh the page
});
```

Comment: This solved it...  I still find it strange that this was happening though... :S

Comment: Some of the other answers suggest that the cause is that a <button></button> is by default a submit button, and changing the type is another solution. However the solution I provided is _technically_ how it should be done. it is the most flexible and will keep your code scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has two submit buttons, the form will submit with the enter key by activating the first submit button.  change

```
<button name="back" tabindex="4">Back</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" name="back" tabindex="4">Back</button>
```

to avoid the browser interpreting the first button as a submit button

Comment: The default type for a [button element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) in a form is submit.